# Mysql - Finding grand parents with from category tree

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to get the grand parents in a tree where status is set as 1, when we have the id of a child category as the where condition in a mysql query

**Category**

```
id | parent_id | name        | status
-------------------------------------
1  | 0         | Cars        |0
2  | 0         | Planes      |0
3  | 1         | Hatchbacks  |1 
4  | 1         | Convertibles|1
5  | 2         | Jets        |1
6  | 3         | Peugeot     |0
7  | 3         | BMW         |1
8  | 6         | 206         |0
9  | 6         | 306         |0
```

In this example , if I have id = 8 then the result get record with id=3

Comment: Hint:  You need two self-joins.

Comment: Doesn't seem PHP relevant.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, a double self join is working.
If there is no grandparent-item available, it won't return any rows
Like Id = 4 in you example, has a parent-item, but no grand-parent-item

```
SELECT catgrandparent.*
  FROM category catchild
 INNER JOIN category catparent
    ON catchild.parent_id = catparent.id
 INNER JOIN category catgrandparent
    ON catparent.parent_id = catgrandparent.id
```

Answer (score 0):

According to description as mentioned in above question please try executing following SQL query

For example to fetch grandparent of category id 8

```
select c.* from category as a join category b on a .parent_id=b.id 
 join category c on c.id=b.parent_id where a.id=8
```